Local Ring at a Closed Point of a Smooth Scheme is an Integral Domain
This is pertaining to Exercise 13.2.O on (the Feb 21, 2024 version of) Vakil's FOAG. The exercise reads

Suppose $p$ is a closed point of a smooth $k$-scheme of dimension $n$. Show that $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ is an integral domain (necessarily of dimension $n$).

I know at this point that a regular local ring is an integral domain, so knowing that $X$ is regular would be sufficient. Theorem 13.2.7 states that every smooth $k$-scheme is regular, but this theorem isn't proven here and thus doesn't appear to be used in the proofs and exercises in this section. As a result, I was wondering if there was a way to do this exercise without the theorem.
The previous proposition tells me that smooth schemes are reduced, so I just need to show that the local ring is irreducible, but it's not clear to me how this is done. A previous result also tells me a locally finite type scheme of pure dimension over an algebraically closed field is smooth if and only if it is regular at its closed points. This tempts me to take the fiber product of $X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k$ along $\operatorname{Spec} \overline{k} \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k$, after which I can conclude that the local rings of $X_{\overline{k}}$ at closed points are regular local rings, and thus integral domains. I don't, however, know how to use this result to make conclusions about the local rings of $X$.

I think this idea is good, if you want to show the local rings are domains. Perhaps you can try showing the map $X_{\overline{k}} \to X$ is surjective? That way, if $p \in X$ there is an inclusion $\mathcal{O}{X, p} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}{X_{\overline{k}}, q}$ for some point $q \in X_{\overline{k}}$.

I believe it's not generally surjective. If $X = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $p = (x^2+1)$, $X_\overline{k} = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[x]$ and I don't believe anything maps to $p$ under $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[x] \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{R}[x]$. Also, if there was a point mapping to $p$, why would we know that the map on local rings is an inclusion?

In this case, the fiber over $p$ is $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2 + 1)\mathbb{C}[x] \cong \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$ by the Chinese remainder theorem. In particular, we can identify the fiber as the set ${(x + i), (x - i)}$.

Relevant questions: Dominant and injective maps and surjectivity base changes

@Daniel the fact that the map is surjective does not necessarily imply that the map on stalks is injective. Consider the inclusion $k[x,y]/(xy)\hookrightarrow k[x]\times k[y]$.

I am also stuck on this question. I don't see how to just use the fact that the stalks of $X_{\overline{k}}$ are domains and both $X$ and $X_{\overline{k}}$ are reduced to conclude that the stalks of $X$ are domains. I feel like one needs to use something more about the fact that $X$ is smooth.

@ManuelAraújo sorry for my mistake. TBH base changing to the algebraic closure seems superfluous, since smooth schemes are already regular. Then it’s a general fact that regular local rings are domains.

@ManuelAraújo I’m a little busy right now but I’ll get back with a comment avoiding this fact.(that smooth implies regular)

Thanks! Yes, I think the idea for this exercise is to avoid using that fact (which won't be proved until much later in the book). We know only that over an algebraically closed field, smooth = regular at closed points. And we know smoothness is preserved by field extensions. And we know that smooth $k$-schemes are reduced, for any $k$.
